# Change invalid password message in AD DS environment

Tags: windows, active-directory, password

I recently changed my organizations password policy from terri-bad to "industry standard" 8 characters with complexity.

With about 5000 users, our helpdesk is now getting inundated with calls from users wondering why "dog123" isn't a valid password anymore and are frustrated at the unhelpful generic "password bad" message Windows 10 displays. (Verbiage was sent out to the users prior to these changes.)

I'm not looking for a way to tell the user what specifically about their password is wrong, but it would be cool if instead of

> Your password is bad for generic possible reasons that may or may not be in place but I won't tell you what those reasons specifically are

I could say

> Password Invalid. $company's password requirements are 8 characters with three of the following: UpperCase, LowerCase, Number, Symbol

I tired looking for .err or some other windows file that contains the error message but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 2):

This prompt isn't something that can be edited [(Source)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61241e3e-fb51-468f-a13d-73bfd4799205/unable-to-change-password-doesnt-meet-complexity-message?forum=win10itprosecurity).  You could look into adding a login banner message [(Technical Details)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-message-text-for-users-attempting-to-log-on) via GPO that includes reminders for something like this and then remove it over time.  But it won't tell them specifically what's wrong with their new password.  There are 3rd party complexity management tools that do what you're asking but nothing built into Windows.